# How would this atmosphere change the way weather works and therefor biomes

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, climate, atmosphere

Is it possible to have a mostly jungle and swamp like planet with these characteristics:

The planet is a mostly water with high amounts of oxygen much like the Carboniferous period on earth.

2 suns and a multi layered ring composed of ice and iron from its previous moon. No moon.

The details:

The planet:
Earth=1
M(mass)=0.7
G(gravity)=0.98
R(radius)=0.9
D(density)=1.09

The atmosphere:
Nitrogen= 60.5
Oxygen= 35
Carbon dioxide=2
Argon= 1.5
Water vapor= 1

If not what would it likely look like?
I’m thinking of a planet with only a select few large biomes.
I don’t care if you change a few things as long as it’s not to different.

Comment: D= Density and R= Radius. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It seems obvious now you point it out, thanks.

Comment: You might want to edit what  M, G, R and D mean into the question.   Comments may be deleted from time to time.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your planet's mass will be closer to 0.8 Earth masses than 0.7. All the other numbers look OK.

Comment: Not saying no but could I ask why?

Comment: Also if I change the earth masses to 0.8 I have to change everything.

Answer (score 1):

I take it from the phrasing "jungle and swamps" this means an tropical forest biome. Jungle is not a scientifically recognised term, but no need to get pedantic.
I see no reason why this specs wouldn't make this a green paradise, they are very Earth-like and a gravity of 9.6 m/s would have no effect on plants.  You stated an atmosphere so there's a magnetic field,  iron core, mantle and so on so all good. Perhaps,  as you mentioned a Carboniferous flora ornated with amphibians, oversized dragonflies and other giant invertebrates would be perfectly adapted although contemporary species would thrive as well.
To get mostly jungles and swamps you'll need most of the landmass close to the Equator and between Tropics. Also consider active volcanoes to keep a good level of CO2 in the atmosphere and "feed" the plants and above else keep the planet from turning into a "Snowball Earth".
The only criticism I can give is ice in the planet's ring. Ice only stays ice in a ring beyond the frost line and out of the habitable zone for the planets so you can have one or the other.